# $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^x$

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to find $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{\!x}$.
I'd like to use the fact that 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{\ln(\cos(1/x)^x)}$$
but I am not sure what to do after this.

Answer (score 1):

Taylor expanding $\cos 1/x$ since as $x$ get's large, the argument of $\cos$ is small, your limit is 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1-\frac{1}{2x^2})^x=L
$$
Then 
$$
\log L=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x\log(1-\frac{1}{2x^2})\stackrel{\text{L'Hôpital's}}{=}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2}{1/x-2x}=0
$$
which then implies that $L=e^0=1$

Comment: You should have $1-1/2x^2$ instead of $1-1/x^2$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh good call, fixing

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln\left[\cos(1/x)^{x}\right]
=x\ln(\cos(1/x))=x\ln\left(1-\frac1{2x^2}+O(x^{-4})\right)
=-\frac1{2x}+O(x^{-3})\to0$$
as $x\to\infty$. So your limit is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x\log\left(\cos \frac{1}{x}\right) &= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}x \frac{\log \cos \frac{1}{x}}{ \cos \frac{1}{x} -1}\left(\cos \frac{1}{x} - 1 \right) \\
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x\cdot 1\cdot (-2\sin ^2 \frac{1}{2x}) \\
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-2\sin ^2 \frac{1}{2x}}{x\frac{1}{x^2}} \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
Hence the required limit is $e^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You are off to a good start!
Note that limits can pass through continuous functions, so starting from what you had we get:
${\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\ln(\cos(1/x))^{x}}=e^{{\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}}\ln(\cos(1/x))^{x}}}=e^{{\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}}x\cdot \ln(\cos(1/x))}= e^{{\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}}x \cdot \ln(\cos(1/x))\cdot \frac{1/x}{1/x}}=e^{{\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}} \frac{\ln(\cos(1/x))}{1/x}}$

Now we can apply L'Hopital's Rule to this limit to get:

$= e^{{\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}}\left( \frac{\frac{1}{\cos(1/x)}\cdot \sin(1/x)\cdot x^{-2}}{-x^{-2}}\right)} =e^{{\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}} -\tan(1/x)}= e^{-\tan\left({\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}}\frac{1}{x}\right)}=e^{-\tan(0)}=e^{-0}=1$

Comment: The way you have put a backslash before "lim" you should also put a backslash before "ln", "cos", "sin"  and "tan" so that they are displayed properly by mathjax.

Comment: Ohhh ... thanks for letting me know.  I'll do that in the future.

Comment: You can edit your answer by clicking on edit link below the answer.

Comment: Perfect editing and +1.

Comment: Thanks ... appreciate you teaching me how to post things better :)

Answer (score 0):

One has
$$x \log\left( \cos\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)\right) = \frac{ \log\left( \cos\left( \frac{1}{x}\right) \right) -\log\left( \cos\left( 0\right) \right)}{\frac{1}{x}-0}$$

so by definition of a derivative,
$$\lim_{ x \rightarrow +\infty} x \log\left( \cos\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)\right) = (\log \circ \cos)'(0) = - \frac{\sin(0)}{\cos(0)} = 0$$

and so
$$\lim_{ x \rightarrow +\infty} \left( \cos\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)\right) ^x = \lim_{ x \rightarrow +\infty} \exp \left[ x \log\left( \cos\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)\right) \right] = \exp(0)=1.$$